# What is bootstrapping (in web development)?

Tags: php, web-applications, web, bootstrapping

I read several articles about php framework and they talked about bootstrapping. I have zero knowledge about bootstrapping, I already searched about them in Google, all I found were about twitter bootstrap etc. which I don't understand.

Can someone please explain what is bootstrapping (especially in web development field) and if you will, please give some examples or link (because I couldn't find a good example for this one).

Comment: PHP is a language, not a framework and there are many frameworks written in PHP. Without knowing the context is hard to give a precise answer of what they mean by bootstrap. Although the concept is general.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Software_loading_and_execution) (first Google result):

> Software loading and execution
>
> The computer term bootstrap began as a metaphor in the 1950s. In
>   computers, pressing a bootstrap button caused a hardwired program to
>   read a bootstrap program from an input unit. The computer would then
>   execute the bootstrap program, which caused it to read more program
>   instructions. It became a self-sustaining process that proceeded
>   without external help from manually entered instructions. As a
>   computing term, bootstrap has been used since at least 1953.